# Joining two tables

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
    st = "SELECT YearLevel FROM Students WHERE StudentID = " & txtStudentID.Text
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(st, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Students")
    YearLevel = ds.Tables("Students").Rows(0).Item("YearLevel")

    st1 = "SELECT TuitionFee, BookFee, MiscellaneousFee, OtherFee FROM Expenses WHERE YearLevel = " & YearLevel

    da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(st1, conn)
    da1.Fill(ds1, "Expenses")
```

So I have that code, then I have an error of missing operator in my second query, what could be the possible solution?

Comment: What is the value of `YearLevel` ?  Could you add a message box to see what the value is?

Comment: the value is 'Grade 1'

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the value for `YearLevel` is `Grade 1` and this needs to be escaped in quotes.  So the actual query which you want your RDBMS to execute probably looks something like this:

```
SELECT TuitionFee, BookFee, MiscellaneousFee, OtherFee
FROM Expenses
WHERE YearLevel = 'Grade 1'
```

You could add quotes directly in the string `st1`, but this might leave the door open for SQL injection.  Here is a safer way to go about doing this:

```
MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TuitionFee, BookFee, MiscellaneousFee, OtherFee FROM Expenses WHERE YearLevel = @YearLevel", conn)
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearLevel", YearLevel)
```

VB.net should sense that the parameter is of character type, and automatically escape it with quotes for you.

Comment: I wanted to call first the YearlLevel from another table that it would match the YearLevel in another table

Comment: The logic you are using seems fine, but I think the syntax is off.  Try my answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: i tried using your code. But it won't connect to the other query i used